# Define a friend function for a static class method?

Tags: c++, fork

Does someone know how to let outside world access private static methods? The only way I could think of is via friend function, but that doesn't seem to work.

Header file here:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
 public:
    friend void AtFork();

 private:
    static void Disp() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
};
```

impl file here:

```
#include "test.h"

namespace {

void AtFork() {
    MyClass::Disp();
}

}

int main() {
    AtFork();
}
```

The error message is:

```
test.cc:6:11: error: 'Disp' is a private member of 'MyClass'
        MyClass::Disp();
                 ^
./test.h:10:15: note: declared private here
        static void Disp() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
```

context: to get fork-safe (due to a bunch of legacy code), I have a reinitialize a 3rd library by binding a fork hook, and I don't think it should be exposed to public.

For the above example, it's let `AtFork` being able to call `MyClass::Disp`.

Comment: Why `AtFork` is defined in anonymous namespace?

Comment: @songyuanyao Since that's the company coding style :(

Comment: It's just not the one in friend decalration, which refers to a global `AtFork`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I would place a named namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is the anonymous namespace. The `AtFork` in `main.cpp` can only be accessed within `main.cpp`. The `AtFork` you declared as friend is a different one. Do not use an anonymous namespace and the code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
 public:
    friend void AtFork();

 private:
    static void Disp() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
};


//namespace {

void AtFork() {
    MyClass::Disp();
}

//}

int main() {
    AtFork();
}
```

Though you can place `AtFork` in a (named) namespace if you like:

```
#include <iostream>


namespace foo { void AtFork();}

class MyClass {
 public:
    friend void foo::AtFork();

 private:
    static void Disp() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
};


namespace foo{

void AtFork() {
    MyClass::Disp();
}

}

int main() {
    foo::AtFork();
}
```

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks!